# joomla installing new language DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (jerror)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I am a fresh installation of Joomla 3.1 running on my home computer.  My environment is Ubuntu 12.10 with apache server, php 5.4.6 installed.  Since installing the system, no I am just trying to install more languages through the language manager:
[image]

As you can see, the 2 additional languages that I wanted show up in the list, but after selecting each language, and clicking "Install", I was led to a page with this message:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (jerror) at position 0 (j): The timezone could not be found in the
>   database

With a button to just go back to the control panel.  I was suprised to see these languages show up in the list.

I also saw this message when I tried (and failed) to install my first component - it was a component to embed google maps in articles.

Anyway, I haven't been able to find a solution for this problem online, I was wondering if anyone out there knows what the problem is.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The problem in my case turned out to be that some on my directories where un-writable.  I went to the "directory permissions" tab under "System Information", and tried to make sure that all the directories were writable.  When  i first opened it, all the directories in the "administrator" directory were not writable, and we changed them to be writable through the shell in linux, then i was able to install the new languages without the error message above.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the most stupid bug in Joomla 3. I wasted 2 days trying to solve this out and I found that the problem was that the **log** and **tmp** paths were not set correctly on the **configuration.php**

Don't worry there's nothing wrong with your Date/Time/Timezone/Localization settings. It's just a stupid silly message that doesn't relate to the actual problem.

To save your time I recommend you get the full path using this script:

```
<?php
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
echo "<p>Full path to this dir: " . $dir . "</p>";
?>
```

Create a PHP file and upload it to Joomla root. It will get you the path correctly

My path looked exactly the same except that there was an **uppercase** letter screwing everything up.

Note that this error could happen if the folders doesn't have the correct permission (not writable)

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, I checked my `configuration.php` and the logs and tmp paths are correct already...  Not sure if maybe it is another problem with my config file.

Comment: Yes I just did, and it path is exactly the same, except there is a `$` character on the end of the output from `dirname(__FILE__)`, but I think that is just a problem with my shell. SO yes the pathname is already correct.

Comment: OK can you check the update and added? Also try adding this `$` I think it is the problem.

Comment: I am not sure about that `$` ... PHP isn't suppose to echo it I think

Comment: I checked system info, and the log and tmp files are writable, but I see that the language/overrides is not writable, and all the administrator folders are not writable...  Do you think it could have something to do with the fact that my session handler is `database`?  The error says coundn't find timezone in database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30203/discussion-between-ahmad-alfy-and-jeffery-the-wind)

Comment: As a start I would say fix the permission issues. I don't think it's related to the timezone or the database to be honest

Comment: I changed all the permissions so that the folders were writable, and that solved the problem!

Comment: Perfect, it isn't a faulty write permission issue then. My case was wrong path and yours is un-writable directories. I will file a bug

Comment: just been cloning a J3 site from one server to another and ran into this issue... it was the tmp and log paths in the config file that I had neglected to change. It looks like you saved me days of work! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have a successful answer for this problem in joomla 3x

**DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (jerror) at position 0 (j): The timezone could not be found in the database**

1. Set the correct path to your joomla site tmp folder

   Log in to joomla administrator Panal 
   System -> global Configuration -> Server

   and give the correct path ("Path To Tmp Folder")

   EX:
   http://www.yourDomain.com/tmp
2. Path to Sloving PHP file

   libraries/joomla/filesystem/folder.php

   Change Online 260 with this code

`__METHOD__ . ': ' . JText::_('JLIB_FILESYSTEM_ERROR_COULD_NOT_CREATE_DIRECTORY'). 'Path: ' . $path, JLog::WARNING, 'jerror'`

Comment: What if you get the error when trying to login to the admin panel? I keep getting the error and the login credentials are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Ok just had the same problem, was helping a friend who couldnt get his new joomla 3 site to install a new template. Every thing looked good in system infomation, all writeable but on looking further I found although plugins/ was marked as writeable I had to change all the permissions for each folder in plugins/ and it worked straight away.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by creating /tmp and /log directories one level above the website root and making them writable.

```
Example:
/home/sitename/log
/home/sitename/tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

this problem cause of changing the host of your joomla and the address of /tmp and /log directory in configuration.php file need correction with new address

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed easily.

go to plugins/system/yt/includes/libs/yt-minify.php

go to this line :

```
$this->optimizeFolder  = $app->getTemplate(true)->params->get('optimizeFolder', 'yt-assets');
```

and change it to :

```
$this->optimizeFolder = $app->getTemplate(true)->params->get('optimizeFolder', 'yt-assets');
$this->optimizeFolder = JPATH_ROOT.'/'.$this->optimizeFolder;
```

hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Admin Tools](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/admin-tools.html) it can cause this to appear when you use the wrong password when trying to login as admin (because it locks directories). Also, it'll give you a heart attack.